# JButtons are not resizing to match their preferred size

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

I am trying to make a menu screen for a game. I've added two buttons, play and exit, and am currently trying to figure out how to resize them. When I run my code the buttons are almost the exact same size (different I imagine because of the text). I'm using BoxLayout for my buttons, and I just read here [Why will BoxLayout not allow me to change the width of a JButton but let me change the height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692987/why-will-boxlayout-not-allow-me-to-change-the-width-of-a-jbutton-but-let-me-chan) why it would only resize the width or height, but it's not resizing either right now. In my code I use BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS, I don't know if that makes a difference, but it didn't resize vertically either with BoxLayout.Y_AXIS.

Here's my code:

```
public class Stage extends JFrame {
/* PRIVATE */
private JButton play, exit;

// Setup the Menu screen.
private void createMenuScreen() {
    Container window = getContentPane();
    // window.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    JPanel menuScreen = new JPanel();
    menuScreen.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menuScreen, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    window.add(menuScreen, "Center");

    play = new JButton("Play");
    play.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
    play.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);



    exit = new JButton("Exit");
    exit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    exit.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    menuScreen.add(play);
    menuScreen.add(exit);
}

/* PUBLIC */
public Stage() {
    // Setup the frame.
    setSize(224, 288);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Centers the window.
    setUndecorated(true); // Removes the Windows border.
    setVisible(true);

    createMenuScreen();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use setMaximumSize() method

`exit.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));`

Or try to use  `BorderLayout` instead of `BoxLayout`

Comment: [Box Layout Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#features)